# python - pyvisa - Trying to read variable length data from device that has no read _termination

Tags: python, pyvisa

I am able to read and write from/to a signal generator using miniterm.py.  There is no read_termination character in the stream, (per the manual from the device manufacturer).  I have attached debug output from miniterm to show a few transactions.  Is there something I am missing to get pyvisa to read an arbitrary length return string without termination?

------------------------miniterm output --------------------------

Settings: /dev/ttyUSB0  9600,8,N,1
RTS: active    DTR: active    BREAK: inactive
CTS: inactive  DSR: inactive  RI: inactive  CD: inactive
software flow control: inactive
hardware flow control: inactive
serial input encoding: UTF-8
serial output encoding: UTF-8
EOL: LF
filters: debug default direct

[TX:'R']  [TX:'M']  [TX:'W']  [TX:'\n']  [RX:'3'] 3 [RX:'6'] 6  [TX:'R']  [TX:'F']  [TX:'W']  [TX:'\n']  [RX:'0'] 0 [TX:'R']  [TX:'M']  [TX:'A']  [TX:'\n']  [RX:'2'] 2 [RX:'0'] 0 [RX:'0'] 0 [TX:'R']  [TX:'F']  [TX:'A']  [TX:'\n']  [RX:'1'] 1 [RX:'0'] 0 [RX:'0'] 0 [RX:'0'] 0

---

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.  This is a really strange type of device.  Most everything I have tried ends in either a 'device in use' or 'timeout' error.

Thank you in advance.

Robin

Answer (score 0):

The read_data() function below solved the problem to some extent.  Now to figure out why back to back writes fail unless time.sleep(x) of about .2 seconds is not used between writes.

```
def read_data(cmd):
    data=""
    byte=""
    looper = True
    dds.write(cmd)
    while(looper==True):
       try:
          byte = dds.read_bytes(1)
          data += byte.decode()
       except:
          looper = False
    return(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a measurement instrument and It took a while to find a solution for this:

`device.bytes_in_buffer` gives you the amount of bytes inside the buffer and

`answer = device.read_bytes( device.bytes_in_buffer )` returns you the bytes inside the bufffer.

After that you can call `answer.decode()` to get the ASCII string the device returned you. Here is a longer example of a Python class I wrote to make communication with the device easier:

```
import pyvisa as visa
import logging as log
import time
from typing import Final, Union

class interface:  # provide write(), read(), read_raw(), ask() and ask_raw() function

    _device = None

    def __init__(self, device) -> None:
        self._device = device

    def write(self, command) -> None:
        self._device.write("%s" % ( command))

    def read(self) -> str:
        return self.read_raw().decode()

    def read_raw(self) -> str:
        return self._device.read_bytes( self._device.bytes_in_buffer )

    def ask(self, command) -> str:
        return self.ask_raw(command).decode()

    # flush buffer, this is necessary to prevent from errors because the last SCPI command took to long to be received
    def flush_buffer(self) -> None:
        self._device.flush(visa.constants.VI_READ_BUF)

    def ask_raw(self, command) -> str:
        self.flush_buffer()
        self.write(command)
        time.sleep(0.2) # this is needed for the device to process the SCPI command
        return self.read_raw()

    def boolean_property(
        self,
        scpi_cmd: str,                  # command name of scpi option
        err_description: str,           # generate usefull error messages
        value: Union[bool, None] = None # True or False -> set scpi option to value, None -> get current value of scpi option
    ) -> Union[bool, None]:

        # if parameter value is None -> get current state from scpi option
        if value == None:
            return {
                "ON": True,
                "1": True,
                "OFF": False,
                "0": False
            }[str(
                self.ask("%s?" % (scpi_cmd.upper()))
            ).upper()]   # uppercase conversion is used to prevent issues with unexpected lowercase letters

        # check wether the parameter is a boolean
        if not type(value) == bool:
            return log.error("%s: Cannot assign \"%s\" for %s, must be bool(True) or bool(False)" % (self._device, value, err_description))

        # write the scpi command
        self.write("%s %s" % (
            scpi_cmd,
            {
                True: "ON",
                False: "OFF"
            }[value]
        ))
```